# Website is in HTML

Tags: adminhtml, html

I am getting this error when I am trying to login in to the HTML website.

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'clubma_dbaytxf.customer_entity' doesn't exist in /home/clubma/public_html/new_clublogin.php:32 Stack trace: #0 /home/clubma/public_html/new_clublogin.php(32): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/clubma/public_html/new_clublogin.php on line 32

Comment: Can you please Explain your User Story what you actually want to Do? i can;t comment on Question i am Asking Here Maybe I can Help you

Answer (score 0):

According to your error specification :

```
customer_entity
```

This table is missing into the database.
So kindly check that things and if missing then create it.

Comment: I did not create this website. Somebody else created. I am a Front end, WordPress developer. I do not know how to fix it? A database table is empty.  I do not know how to create the table?

Comment: What is actually name of this table "customer_entity"? Any thing added before this one or something?

Comment: Actually old developer solved it. Thank you so much Dhiren.